# Как это будет выглядеть на ванильном JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
/* Если высота окна + высота прокрутки больше или равны высоте всего документа и ajax-запрос в настоящий момент не выполняется, то запускаем ajax-запрос */  

if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 200) {}
```

Comment: Исходники jQuery же есть, вот их раскопать постепенно и понять.

Comment: Тут много разных выражений, нужно уточнить какую именно часть Вам сложно перевести на ванильный JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать так:

```js
const windowScroll = () => {
 return window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}

const windowHeight = () => {
 return window.innerHeight;
}

const documentHeight = () => {
 return document.documentElement.offsetHeight 
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
 
 if ( windowHeight() + windowScroll() >= documentHeight() - 200 )  {
  console.log('true')
 }
})
```

```css
html {
 height: 2000px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset == document.documentElement.scrollHeight) {}
```

Comment: условия не равнозначные

Answer (score -1):

```js
if (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight >= document.documentElement.clientHeight - 200)
```

Comment: Вы знаете, что можно исправить и восстановить удаленный ответ?

Comment: document.documentElement.clientHeight разве должен быть равен высоте окна??